# Were there any programs besides editors that relied on on the O_NDELAY file status flag (predecessor to O_NONBLOCK)

Tags: io, history, historical-unix

Recently, I've been researching on the `O_NONBLOCK` feature specified in the standard.

From what I've seen so far, the predecessor of this flag - `O_NDELAY` had existed all the way back to UNIX System III. I assume this is because was the only way to "poll" files for IO availability (`poll` and `select` didn't exist until the STREAMS and Sockets days). The standard developers chose to invent the `O_NONBLOCK` flag because it was deemed undesirable to conflict with the return-0-on-EOF semantic.

Were there any programs that relied on `O_NDELAY`? I can think of text editors as one such kind of programs (because they may want to occasionally save backups), but were there others?